# Pendulum with friction: La Sall's Invariance Theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction, stability

I am trying to understand la Sall's Invariance Theorem, which is used to proove that a system is aysmptotically stable.

Can someone help me to understand it, by making an example of how to use it. For instance, a pendulum with friction might be a perfect candidate...

$\dot{x_1} = x_2$

$\dot{x_2} =-g\sin(x_1)-b/m \, x_2$

[image]

... since the pendulum is asymptotically stable.
[image]

A Lyapunov candidate would be:

$V=E_{kin}+E_{pot} = \frac{1}{2} m x_2^2+mg(1-\cos(x_1))$